# Create multidimensionnal array with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a multidimensionnale array using a for loop.
The result i need is :

```
[
 [1, 2, 3], 
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]
]
```

So how can i loop from 1 to 10 and each 3 numbers i create a new array ?
I don't find a solution.. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3):

This should be what you're looking for:

```js
var outer = [];
var inner = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  inner.push(i);
  if (inner.length == 3) {
    outer.push(inner);
    inner = [];
  }
}
if (inner.length > 0) outer.push(inner);

console.log(outer);
```

Remove the `if` after the loop, if you don't want any elements with less than 3 inner elements.

Answer (score 1):

This *might* be the simplest solution:

```js
const result = [];
for(let i = 1; i < 10; i = i + 3) {
  result.push([i, i+1, i+2]);
}
console.log(result);
```

If you're sure you want 3 consecutive numbers, you can loop from 1 to 10 skipping 3 every time, so your `i` inside `for` loop would be `1`, then `4` and then `7` in last iteration. With every iteration you create `[i, i+1, i+2]` array on the spot and push it to `result` array. However this solution is based on above conditions. It works well for `10`, for *any* number it would require additional `if` statement inside `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = 1;
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
     array[i][j] = ++c;
```

Comment: While this code snippet might solve the issue, including an explanation with the snippet is recommended, so we know how it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop and use a variable for the first index of the 2D array.

```js
var i, r, array = [];

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    r = Math.floor(i / 3);
    array[r] = array[r] || [];
    array[r].push(i + 1);
}

console.log(array);
```